# Use get function instead of if statement to assign values to keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I was asked to replace the if statements in the following function histogram(s) with `d.get()`, which assigns a key a corresponding value.

```
def histogram(s):
    d = dict()
    for c in s:
        if c not in d:
            d[c] = 1
        else:
            d[c] += 1
    return d
print(histogram('happy'))
```

This is what I tried:

```
def ordered_items(s):
    d = dict()
    for c in s:  
        d[c] = 1
        d.get(c, 0)
    return d
print(ordered_items('happy'))
```

I was expecting it to take each character in s and assign it the value 1 and that's what happened, but what I need the program to do is give each key the correspond value that counts how many times the character appears in the word. I'm having trouble assigning the characters to keys in the dictionary and incrementing the value for every time another of the same character appears. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that the line `d.get(c, 0)` is basically doing nothing. You `.get()` the value but you don't use it.

You can do the following:

```py
def histogram(s):
    d = {}
    for c in s:
        d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + 1
    return d
```

---

The rest is not what you asked for but another usual ways in Python to do this:

Use a `defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def histogram(s):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for c in s:
        d[c] += 1
    return d
```

Or the fastest way is to use `Counter`:

```py
from collections import Counter

def histogram(s):
    return Counter(s)
```